# How to prove integration by substitution for Lebesgue measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The problem I'm having trouble answering is: Suppose $h$ is a differentiable function on $[a,b]$ with a continuous, positive derivative $h'(y)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. For a measurable subset $\lambda\subset[a,b]$, show that $m(h(\lambda)) = \int_{\lambda}h'$. Then, use this to prove the Integration by substitution formula, namely that $$\int_a^bf(g(x))g'(x)dx = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(t)dt.$$

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I should go about solving this?

Comment: I made some minor changes in formatting and chose a slightly more informative title ("measure and integration") is a bit too generic to be of any use in searches. :) If you don't like it you can always change it again.

Comment: You just need $F$ to be Absolutely continuous and increasing!

Comment: The idea of the title of a question would be that they reveal something about the content. "Proving measurability" has absolutely nothing to do with your question. Please do make an effort and be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\bf Hint:$ If $h'(y)$ is always positive then $h$ is an increasing function. It follows that for any interval $I=(c,d)\subseteq [a,b], \ h((c,d))=(h(c),h(d))$. In this particular case $m(h(I))=m((h(c),h(d))=h(d)-h(c)=\int_{(c,d)}h'$. For the general case, use approximations to $\lambda$ by open sets.

Comment: @Patrick You are right $d-c$ should be $h(d)-h(c)$ and the result follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.